# Moving image on click in R with gganimate

Tags: r, click, gganimate

I just started using the awesome [gganimate](https://gganimate.com/articles/gganimate.html) package, and I managed to create a [pretty cool animated gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH0fS.gif).
However, I would like the image to move from one state to another on click, not automatically. Is there a way to do that with the gganimate package or with another package?

Thank you,

Sarah

Answer (score 0):

I am 2 short of reputations for commenting hence answering directly, otherwise would have asked for data & code, nevertheless I'll try to answer based on understanding from the linked gif.

Since the main aim of gganimate is to create animations which are simply stitched frames from ggplot output, so to my knowledge there is no option to have a click functionality directly.

This would require a package which has capability for interactive graphics, hence `plotly` is best option. Not trying to demean `gganimate` (I am myself a big fan of it).

```r
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Dim1 = runif(100,-200,200), Dim2 = rpois(100,5), 
                 Timepoint = rep(c("PRE","4WP"),50), pop = runif(100,1,10))

gg <- ggplot(df, aes(Dim1, Dim2)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = pop, frame = Timepoint))

ggplotly(gg) %>% 
  animation_opts(
    frame = 1000,
    transition = 1000,
    easing = "linear",
    redraw = TRUE,
    mode = "immediate"
  )
```

you can try more `easing` options from [plotly/animation_attributes.js](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/plots/animation_attributes.js#L78).
This will directly create a interactive plot:
[image: plotly]
Another option would be to use same animations from `gganimate` by first saving each frame generated by it in file system using: (as I dont know how you are creating your animation I will create a basic one)

```
p <- gg + transition_states(Timepoint, transition_length = 100, state_length = 5)
animate(p, renderer = file_renderer(prefix = "gganim_plot", overwrite = TRUE))
```

which can then be fed into `saveHTML` command of `animation` R package.