# Can I control when animation appears on gganimate by a click?

Tags: r, click, transition, gganimate

I want to make my animations for a powerpoint that I am presenting and so am using gganimate for my data. However, I would like the next set of data to only cycle in when I click as I will be speaking over the data, is this possible? (in transition_states?)

```
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "{closest_state}") +
  transition_states(Species, transition_length = 3, state_length = 1)
```

For example, with this data set above - can I get each Species' data to only cycle in upon clicking? If this is not possible, is there a way that I can control the time between different species cycling in?

Let me know your thoughts.

Best wishes!

Comment: Since you need an animated GIF/movie for use in Powerpoint, I don't think this is possible. Having been in a similar situation, I ended up using a `plotly` animation within an `ioslides` presentation, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61880870/moving-image-on-click-in-r-with-gganimate).

Comment: You could put pauses in your animation, render as avi, and pause if you want more time. Or you could render multiple gifs that each pertain to one segment and put them on successive slides.

Comment: Dear Jon and Maurits, thanks for your comments. I found a solution - I screen recorded the animation and inserted into Powerpoint as a video. Powerpoint then lets you play the video as a click inside the animation.